# Add CLASSPATH to Oozie workflow job

Tags: apache-spark, hive, oozie

I coded SparkSQL that accesses Hive tables, in Java, and packaged a jar file that can be run using `spark-submit`.

Now I want to run this jar as an Oozie workflow (and coordinator, if I make workflow to work). When I try to do that, the job fails and I get in Oozie job logs

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
```

What I did was to look for the jar in `$HIVE_HOME/lib` that contains that class, copy that jar in the `lib` path of my Oozie workflow root path and add this to `workflow.xml` in the Spark Action:

```
<spark-opts> --jars lib/*.jar</spark-opts>
```

But this leads to another `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` that points to another missing class, so I did the process again of looking for the jar and copying, run the job and the same thing goes all over. It looks like it needs the dependency to many jars in my Hive lib.

What I don't understand is when I use spark-submit in the shell using the jar, it runs OK, I can SELECT and INSERT into my Hive tables. It is only when I use Oozie that this occurs. It looks like that Spark can't see the Hive libraries anymore when contained in an Oozie workflow job. Can someone explain how this happens?

How do I add or reference the necessary classes / jars to the Oozie path?

I am using Cloudera Quickstart VM CDH 5.4.0, Spark 1.4.0, Oozie 4.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the "edge node" (the one you can connect to) has a lot of stuff pre-installed and referenced in the default CLASSPATH.
But the Hadoop "worker nodes" are probably barebones, with just core Hadoop libraries pre-installed.

So you can wait a couple of years for Oozie to package properly Spark dependencies in a ShareLib, and use the "blablah.system.libpath" flag.

*[EDIT]* if base Spark functionality is OK but you fail on the Hive format interface, then specify a *list* of ShareLibs including "HCatalog" e.g.

```
action.sharelib.for.spark=spark,hcatalog
```

Or, you can find out which JARs and config files are actually used by Spark, upload them to HDFS, and reference them (all of them, one by one) in your Oozie Action under <file> so that they are downloaded at run time in the working dir of the YARN container.

*[EDIT]* Maybe the ShareLibs contain the JARs but not the config files; then all you have to upload/download is a list of valid config files (Hive, Spark, whatever)

Answer (score 1):

The better way to avoid the ClassPath not found exception in Oozie is, Install the Oozie SharedLib in the cluster, and update the Hive/Pig jars in the Shared Locaton {Some Times Existing Jar in Oozie Shared Location use to get mismatch with product jar.}
hdfs://hadoop:50070/user/oozie/share/lib/
once the same has been update, please pass a parameter 
"oozie.use.system.libpath        =   true"

These will inform oozie to read the Jars from Hadoop Shared Location.

Once the You have mention the Shared Location  by setting the paramenter "true" you no need to mention all and each jar one by one in workflow.xml